# How do I expand my partition

Tags: partition

I am running out of space on my `/dev/sda1` partition for my Kali Linux VM. How do I extend it to include the `/dev/sda2`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove `/dev/sda2` and then you will be able to extend `/dev/sda1`. Do not forget to extend also the filesystem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I extend the filesystem?

Comment: Go to here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask and ask new question